# How to make a skypebot kick someone?

Tags: bots, azure-bot-service, skypedeveloper, skype-bots, microsoft-skype-bot

So if I say for example 'live:1234567_89' I want the bot to kick a certain member.
This is the code by now , it just send a message to group("/kick live:1234567_89"), no kick the member out of the group? how can kick member out of the group by skype Bot?

```
    var activity2 = new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Activity()
{
    Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
    Recipient = new ChannelAccount() { Id = conversationGroupId  },
    From = new ChannelAccount() { Id = botID },
    Text = "/kick live:1234567_89"                          
};
var createMessage = new ConversationParameters()
{
    Members = new ChannelAccount[] { new ChannelAccount() { Id = conversationGroupId  }
    },
    Bot = new ChannelAccount() { Id =  botID },
                                                                 
};  
var conversation2 = await connector.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(createMessage); 
                                                       
var response2 = await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(activity2, conversation2.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it doesn't appear to be the source of your issue with the BotFramework SDK. I don't know for certain, but it doesn't look to me that bots can perform slash commands in Skype. They either require special permissions (or are blanket restricted) or the commands are only recognized via keyboard entry (i.e., meaning the slash command is typed in first and then is followed by any other values vs. the whole text simply being entered in by the bot).

This [doc](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34929/what-chat-commands-are-available-in-skype) lists all available commands, including '/kick' which is an admin level command. Regardless, any slash command I attempted to have the bot issue only came thru as text.

There are several resources available at the bottom of the link included above. Perhaps one of them can help shed more light on if, and how, this can be achieved.